# Spring authentication scheme using the authentication header

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, web, spring-security, webhooks

I am using a spring boot application and I have a web security config adapter set up to authenticate each request using the jwt.

I want to expand my service to allow a different api end point to be authenticated using the header. One of the services I am integrating with sends a web hook and all it sends is the request with the custom header I set it up to include. How can I set up a specific endpoint to only authenticate using a custom header?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `OncePerRequestFilter` to filter the requests to that endpoint and return a 401 if they are do not contain your header with the right value.

You would define your filter:

```
public class HeaderSecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String value = request.getHeader("Token");
        if(value == null || !value.equals("Secret")) {
            response.sendError(401);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

And then register it:

```
@Configuration
public class HeaderSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<HeaderSecurityFilter> filterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<HeaderSecurityFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new HeaderSecurityFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/some/path/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Which would require the header of `Token` be present with a value of `Secret` for anything under `/some/path/*`.

You would also need to ensure through your oauth configuration that you open up access to `/some/path/*`.